# How to sync entities in an ECS game?

Tags: libgdx, networking, synchronization, entity-component-system

I'm wondering how to engineer a client server sync of entities in a multiplayer game which is using an ECS.

When the server changes some values of the components of an entity, I thought the best approach is to send a new update message over the network,
which holds some ID or name of the entity. And then on the client site, I'm trying to resolve the client-side-counterpart of that entity.

But, In my ECS solution (ashley) the entities are not held in a list. So I can't just search for a special entity by ID or something.

I was thinking about giving every entity a new component like "NetworkSyncComponent" which holds an ID, but than
I have to iterate over all entities on the target system which are holding such an component. This seems very bad and slow approach for me.

**TL;DR**
Can you tell me what a better (faster/performance optimized) technique could look like?

Comment: Your network sync component suggestion sounds like a good solution, and is a route I've seen implemented in multiple successful systems. The strength of this is that it lets you separate a collection of entities that need network replication (eg. player characters, dynamic objects...) from those that do not (eg. static world elements that don't change, UI & effects under local authority). This can make traversing the replicated components and applying updates more efficient than grabbing individual entities at random.

Comment: Thx @DMGregory this is a very helpful statement! But don't you think, that traversing that complete subset of entities every message (up to 60 times the second) is a little bit slow?

Comment: No, this is already a small subset of the components in the game, many of which we already iterate over 60+ times per second, and message rates are typically lower than this. There's no reason to repeat the traversal over every component for every message. You can decode the messages into a batch, then process each component that needs a network update and fetch the corresponding message payload for that component instance, or process each message payload and fetch the corresponding component instance.